# How to remove character after @ in javascripts?

Tags: javascript

How to remove character after @ in javascripts ?

for example, I have string '**babibu@blabla.com**', I want to get string before @ '**babibu**', how to do that?

Comment: `str.match(/[^@]+/)`

Comment: This reminds me of those spam emails where'd you'd receive one of those generic auto-generated greetings like "Dear babibu,"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to do this:

**1. Regex**

Use the regex `/^(.*)@/`

[Regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/o6rrMP/1)

Demo:

```js
var email = 'babibu@blabla.com';

var username = email.match(/^(.*)@/)[1];

console.log(username);
```

**2. Array.split()**

```js
var email = 'babibu@blabla.com';

var username = email.split('@', 1)[0];

console.log(username);
```

Comment: Why a regex for something where the simplest string manipulation will do?

Comment: @vlaz why a string manipulation for something whose intention can be clearly indicated by a simple and expressive regex?

Comment: I have added string manipulation solution as well, using Array.split() @vlaz

Comment: Because the regex is unnecessary and I see lots of people throw regex at trivial problems. `str.split("@")[0]` is literally all that's needed. I cannot see why you can say a regex is simpler or clearer than code that pretty much documents itself already, whereas you yourself needed to add a regex explanation.

Comment: @RahulDesai it would probably be preferable to specify [the optional `limit` parameter here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) like `email.split('@', 1)[0]`, to avoid unneeded string processing since we don't care about anything after the first `@` anyway.

Comment: @vlaz at least here, regex terminates its scan at the first `@` while `str.split()` firstly scans the whole string, and secondly generates an array from which we only use the first entry, which is somewhat wasteful. Also, I didn't add the explanation, I personally think the regex here is self-explanatory.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Nothing in the OP suggests to me there would be multiple `@` signs. It seems very straight forward - get an email and fetch the name part.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to regex:

```
var username = email.split('@')[0];
```